# Ajax post a form (validation) in MVC AsP.net?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

So I have a page that have a few forms on it and one of those forms is a one for addresses which has three functions. Save as new, Update and Delete.  I want to use form.submit() to fire the MVC validation on the client and server side but I dont want the entire page refresh.

So this is what I want to use the simple form.submit() to gather the elements and send it to the ASP.net MVC controller as a model and handle the validation based on the attributes I have on the model and use a callback to handle a JSON response to update only the affected area.

I know I could use jQuery to create an AJAX post request but I would have to handle everything, i.e. bind to the viewmodel, validation and create the request itself.  Is there anyway I can get the best of both methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MVC, once you validate Model data using DataAnnotations attributes you have already done with server side validation and then you can use `jQuery.validation library` to validate on client side.

Here you can use Ajax.BeginForm post where you utilize DataAnnotations validation with ajax post.

**DataAnnotations attributes**

```
   public class Movie {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

**jQuery.validation library**

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Form with validation**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
   {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Movie</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
    </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

Resource : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Answer (score 5):

Also do not forget in Post Method in Controller to check

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
```

because client side validation will not validate hidden fields also if you will use ctr+shift+i in any browser and you will delete an  `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)` client validation will not validate this attribute.