# Microsoft MVC : display an error or helpmessage overlay

Tags: ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My web forms display messages in an overlay when a user clicks on a "help" icon next to a form input, or when an input fails a validation rule.

These messages are sometimes assembled dynamically as the user works his way through the data-entry form; the content of the message is based on values entered in other input elements; so the messages cannot be static and kept as data-help-message content inside each HTML element.

So far, I've been doing this client-side, but am learning MVC, and would like to know how to accomplish the same thing using server-side code that changes the Razor view.

In client-side approach, the following javascript toggles the div's visibility and injects an HTML string to show to the user.

```
function overlay(msgHTML) {
        el = document.getElementById("overlay");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
        if (el.style.visibility=="visible") {
            msg = document.getElementById("errmsg");
            msg.innerHTML = msgHTML;
        }

    }
```

What is counterpart functionality in MVC5 with Razor?  How would C# in the controller toggle the div's visibility, or toggle a css class; and how would the error message content get injected?

Again, this has to happen over and over again as the user works with the form. It isn't something known when the form is first rendered, so it would have to be done with Ajax.

Comment: Kindly explain any downvote as I am just learning MVC and don't know if what I'm asking violates the paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically display views based on some criteria, then you should use PartialViews.  You can render them on the server and then, using Ajax, get the string and push the contents into some div:

Your controller action - This is the action that will return the view that you want to show in your popup by [Rendering the Partial View to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494741/mvc-5-render-view-to-string):

```
public ActionResult MyPartialPopupView(MyCriteria someCriteria)
{
    var returnData = new ReturnData{View = this.RenderViewToString("_MyPartialPopupView",someCriteria)};            
    return Json(returnData );
}
```

You could expand on the above by dynamically determining which partial to render based on some info in your someCriteria parameter, such as a help partial, error partial, etc.

Your _MyPartialPopupView.cshtml partial view - This is the partial view that will hold the actual html that will get render in your MyPartialPopupView action:

```
@model MyCriteria

<div>do your model bindings here</div>
```

Then, when you want to use it, you would do something like this in your javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/MyPartialPopupView",
    data: myCriteria,
    success: function (returnData) {  
        $("#myPopup").html(returnData.View); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful PartialViews information. For the help-message scenario, the client can request the controller to send back content and the client would stuff the content where it needs to go. That's essentially what I'm doing now, without MVC and Razor.  But if the validation is moved server-side (e.g. no longer using something like knockout on the client) and the server needs to display an error for the user, is there something like a server-to-client "bridge" that would allow the server to invoke a client-side function?

Comment: The server cannot invoke the client in MVC, unless you use something like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc).  However, you can use [Ajax.Forms and MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060204/ajax-post-a-form-validation-in-mvc-asp-net) to validate user data and display some error.  Or your returnData object can have an Error property and some error object that you use to render an error on the client side (possibly using knockout, but at least all your logic is server side).  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks again for the links to Ajax.Forms and SignalR.